# Extract href from html with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the value of href from an anchor. The code looks like this

`var html = "<a href='http://path/to/file.pdf'>File</a&gt;";

alert(jQuery("a",html).attr("href"));`

The only output I get is 'undefined'.
I'm want to get "http://path/to/file.pdf".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```
jQuery(html).attr('href');
```

Or if the `<a>` tag is deeper in the html than your example:

```
jQuery(html).find('a').attr('href');
```

The `jQuery()` function will convert HTML strings into DOM objects, and return a jQuery object containing them for you.

Comment: Nice and concise. Also good job for explaining why the `$(html)` business works.

Comment: +1.  Just a note to the OP, I would avoid using "html" as a variable name, since jquery has a function called .html() which is used quite often.

Comment: As a note to others looking for this, you can also do `jQuery(html).get(0).href` and use vanilla javascript.

Comment: Great stuff! Works a treat! Thank you all. :)

Comment: @Craig - Sounds like you've accepted this answer. Don't forget to click the checkmark next it to confirm.

Answer (score 3):

To explain why your method doesn't work - when you do `jQuery("a",html)`, you are searching for a elements inside the context of the element stored in html.

The only thing currently inside is the File text. If your string was wrapped in a div for example, it would work. `<div><a href='...'>File</a></div>`

---

I assume you have some other reason for creating a jQuery object. If not, and you don't want the extra overhead, you could use a regular expression.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/e3Gyc/

```
var html = "<a href='http://path/to/file.pdf'>File</a>";

var result = html.match(/href='([^']+)'/)[1];
```

Otherwise the answers that **gnarf** and **Dzida** gave are excellent.

Comment: Ooo, on one hand, The explaination for `jQuery("a", html)` not working is great... On the other you are *gasp* advocating parsing HTML with RegExp... Risky Move - +1 :)

Comment: @gnarf - Thanks for the + . :o) No, not advocating. I'm far too apathetic to be much of an advocate. ;o) Just making a point that you wouldn't necessarily need to create a jQuery object if fetching the `href` is the only purpose. Not likely the case, though. Admittedly, the usefulness of this solution is narrow and fraught with peril. +1 backatcha.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like to make it works as you want:

```
var html = "<a href='http://path/to/file.pdf'>File</a>";
alert($(html).attr("href"))
```